# How to UPDATE after DELETE in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update the table after deleting value in different table.

This is my simplified function query for this question:

```sql
create function updateoutfit(_id uuid,  _title text DEFAULT NULL::text)
    returns TABLE(id uuid, title text)
    language sql
as
$$
WITH del AS (DELETE FROM outfit_garment WHERE outfit_garment.outfit_id = _id RETURNING outfit_id),
     updateOutfit AS (
       UPDATE outfit SET
         title = _title
         FROM del
         WHERE outfit.id = del.outfit_id
         RETURNING id, title
     )
SELECT id,
       title
from updateOutfit as outfit
group by id, title;
$$;
```

It works well if there is outfit_id returned from delete:

```sql
DELETE FROM outfit_garment WHERE outfit_garment.outfit_id = _id RETURNING outfit_id
```

but fails if there is no row to delete. I tried something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM outfit_garment WHERE outfit_garment.outfit_id = '1234' RETURNING (SELECT '1234' as outfit_id );
```

but it still returns 0 rows.

Is there a way to fix that or better way to do it?

I am using postgres 13.2

Comment: Please always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `UPDATE` should be unconditional. So separate the `DELETE`. Like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION updateoutfit(_id UUID, _title text DEFAULT NULL::text)
  RETURNS table(id UUID, title text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
DELETE FROM outfit_garment
WHERE  outfit_garment.outfit_id = _id;

WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE outfit
   SET    title = _title
   FROM   del
   WHERE  outfit.id = _id
   RETURNING id, title
   )
SELECT DISTINCT id, title
FROM   upd;
$func$;
```

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter My query is actually not full. UPDATE is unconditional but I do have INSERT after Update which is conditional to DELETE in the same function, shall I update my question query?

Comment: @Anita: If it changes the nature of the question after an answer has been given, rather ask a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: I have updated the query, I think the question is still valid :) Thanks for suggestion. I hope now its a bit clearer.

Comment: Sure, a valid question, but that's not the point. The point is, it's different and invalidates existing answer(s).

Comment: I created a new question, sorry for that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69501214/how-to-update-after-delete-if-delete-doesnt-return-row-in-postgresql